# How tough is magento2 to understand compared to magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1

Actually, I used Magento 1.9.1.1 .magento 2 is easily understand than Magento 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,magento2 is not easly like magento1.X version.

In magento2 has  use lots of modern Like

- php namespace
- Khockoutjs
- Requirs js
- UI component
- Docker

Etc,

This boots site speedup and security.

Also at magento commerce give solid developer Dev document  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ which will help you to undestand magento2.Magento2 is future of magento

Comment: You can also add terminal commands. Terminal commands that in Magento 1.x were not default only with `magerun-98` and modular modules